# How can make an object in side Array and push to object- javascript ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

```
var TableData = [{
        str: "",
        val: "",
    }];

    TableData[0].str = "11";
    TableData[0].val = "22";

    TableData[1].str = "11";
    TableData[1].val = "22";

    console.log(TableData[0])

    // i need this output {str : "11", val : "22" }
```

but i have this Message in Console :

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'atr' of undefined*

Comment: Initialize the TableData as `[{...}, {}]`

Comment: Because index `1` doesn't exist in `TableData`

Comment: Tushar, i have this Error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: @EmadAlhamou Check it for [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @Mohammad thanx Mohammad :)

Comment: @Mohammad You are not helping him. What does this question has to do with "Spread syntax'?

Comment: @undefined He said *Unexpected token }* to Tushar about using `[{...}, {}]`

Comment: @Tushar He meant initialize the array with 2 objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got errors because there is nothing in index 1 of your array. Put empty object on the index before assigning `str` and `val`:

```js
var TableData = [];

TableData[0] = {};
TableData[0].str = "11";
TableData[0].val = "22";

TableData[1] = {};
TableData[1].str = "11";
TableData[1].val = "22";

console.log(TableData[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the `Uncaught TypeError` for treating `undefined` as an object. `TableData[1]` is `undefined` vs. `TableData[0]` which is an *object*. You need to set the second element to an object before setting the properties:

```
TableData[1] = {};
TableData[1].str = "11";
TableData[1].val = "22";
```

That being said, you can also use the `Array.prototype.push` and an object literal:

```
TableData.push({
   str: "11"
   ...
})
```

Answer (score -1):

try this much

```
var TableData = [{
        str: "",
        val: "",
    }];

    TableData[0].str = "11";
    TableData[0].val = "22";


    console.log(TableData[0])
```

error is happening as you are trying to assign something to element at index `1` for the array , which doesn't exist

Comment: i have this error :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'str' of undefined